# Как правильно написать через css эффект текста на полке?

Tags: html, css

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я поступил так
согнул border но вот текст обратно выгнуть не получается

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">

  #news_head {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #B85C00;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border: thin dashed #111111;
    display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  }

  #news_head > .span {
     color: #777777;
     /*выравниваю текст обратно*/
        -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  }

  #news_content {
    color: #777777;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

   <div id="news_head">
      <span >
      заголовок
      </span>
   </div>

   <div id="news_content">
      текст<br><br>
   </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так: текст в одном блоке, а "полка" в другом

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ground {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  margin: -20px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text">
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="ground">
  </div>
</div>
```